# Passing value in pipeline operator

Tags: r, dplyr, pipeline

I'm workinng in R with two tables connected by id variable (and for some reasons I don't want to merge them). The exemplary objects are presented below:

```
a <- data.frame(id=c(1L,2L,3L),
            var1=c(0,1,3))
b <- data.frame(id=c(1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L),
            var2=rnorm(6))
```

What I want to do is find rows in first database with respect to given condition on var1, select only Ids and then use these id values to filter observation in database 2. I wonder if I can do this in one pipeline, as follows:

```
a %>% 
filter(var1==1) %>% 
select(id) %>%
filter(b,id==.)
```

Or

```
a %>% 
filter(var1==1) %>% 
select(id) %>% c() %>% unlist()
filter(b,id==.)
```

Both examples doesn't work probably because I can pass only data.frames or other objects through pipeline operator and not atomic values. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're looking for a `semi_join`:

```
a %>% filter(var1 == 1) %>% semi_join(b, ., by = "id")
#  id       var2
# 1  2  0.8283845
# 2  2 -0.5286006
```

> **semi_join**
>
> return all rows from x where there are matching values in y,
>   keeping just columns from x.
>
> A semi join differs from an inner join because an inner join will
>   return one row of x for each matching row of y, where a semi join will
>   never duplicate rows of x.

Comment: `dplyr` just keeps on giving. I would add to your answer that `semi_join` comes from `dplyr`.

Comment: Thank's, I figured it out but I'd like to know the answer for question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers give good solutions how to get the desired result. To answer the question you ask at the end of your question:

Your examples don't fail because the pipeline is somehow limited in what it pipes through. The problem lies in what the pipeline operator , `%>%`, actually does. It pipes the result of the left hand side as the FIRST argument of the right hand side, regardless of where you use `.`. So where you have `filter(b,id==.)` It won't filter b, it's actually filtering the result of your previous statements. You can see this when you call `traceback()` on your first example. If we look at the two relevant results:

```
....
9: filter(., b, id == .)
....
1: a %>% filter(var1 == 1) %>% select(id) %>% filter(b, id == .)
```

At `1:` We see your code, but at `9:` we see what is actually read by R. the `filter(b, id == .)` is actually being read as `filter(., b, id == .)`

Comment: here one question was even `b` should have been `group_by` right? correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I don't think `group_by` would've come into play here, `group_by` is mostly if you have multiple grouping variables in one data.frame, not for dealing with multiple data.frames.

Comment: Also could anyone explain the downvote? (preferably the downvoter)

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply make it a two stage process:

```
selected_ids = a %>% filter(var1 == 1) %>% select(id) %>% unlist()
b %>% filter(id %in% selected_ids)
#   id       var2
# 1  2  0.8054040
# 2  2 -0.5000918
```

or merge the datasets and perform the operation directly:

```
merged_data = merge(a, b)
merged_data %>% filter(var1 == 1)
#   id var1       var2
# 1  2    1  0.8054040
# 2  2    1 -0.5000918
```

I prefer this second option.

Answer (score 0):

We can get `id` from `a` where `var = 1` and select all the rows in `b` where the `id` matches

```
b[b$id %in% a$id[a$var1 == 1], ]

#  id   var2
#3  2 1.0294
#4  2 0.7369
```

The similar thing can be done in `dplyr` by

```
library(dplyr)
b %>%
filter(id == a$id[a$var1 == 1])
```

Comment: I agree that this yields the correct answer. The OP is requesting a `dplyr` based answer though...

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
setDT(a)[b, on = "id"][var1==1]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
left_join(b, a, by = "id") %>% 
                     filter(var1==1)
```

Comment: For some reasons I didn' want to join - but yes in 99% of cases this is an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work (though I agree with others that I prefer a merge or join of some sort).

You can get around the inclusion of `.` as the first argument by including brackets around your expression (`{}`). Then, treat `.` as a data.frame (which it is, even after `select`), and call the column you want. Like so:

```
a %>% 
  filter(var1==1) %>% 
  {filter(b,id==.$id)}
```

returns:

```
  id       var2
1  2 -0.2992151
2  2 -0.4115108
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to be the best answer :)